# Error "el paramentro no es valido" .net SDK HIKVISION

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

Estoy realizando la captura de fotografia desde mi reloj biometrico utilizando el SDK de Hikvision. Pero al momento de presionar el boton de capturar en mi form. Rapidamente el reloj se activa para de tomar la fotografia y posterior guardar la imagen en una carpeta local.. Pero no se hace posible y no se cual sea el problema.
Obtengo el siguiente ERROR: El parametro no es valido

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string szUrl = "/ISAPI/AccessControl/CaptureFaceData";
    string szResponse = string.Empty;
    string szRequest = "<CaptureFaceDataCond version=\"2.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema\"><captureInfrared>false</captureInfrared><dataType>binary</dataType></CaptureFaceDataCond>";

    if (!szUrl.StartsWith("http"))
    {
        szUrl = "http://" + AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strDeviceIP + ":" + AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strHttpPort + szUrl;
    }

    HttpClient clHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    szResponse = clHttpClient.HttpCapData(AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strUsername, AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strPassword, szUrl, string.Empty, szRequest);

    string codigoUsuario = textBoxEmployeeNo.Text;
    string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\dsolares\Documents\Pruebas desarrollo\Evento Foto", $"{codigoUsuario}.jpg");

    try
    {
        // Guarda la imagen en el archivo con el nombre del código de usuario
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(szResponse));

        // Carga la imagen en el PictureBox
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            pictureBoxFace.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar o cargar la imagen: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

public string HttpCapData(string strUserName, string strPassword, string url,
    string filePath, string request)
{
    string responseContent = string.Empty;
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    // 设置属性  
    webRequest.Credentials = GetCredentialCache(url, strUserName, strPassword);
    webRequest.Timeout = m_iHttpTimeOut;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml,";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "zh-CN");
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
    webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    
    var contentLine = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n");
    memStream.Write(contentLine, 0, contentLine.Length);
    //写入JSON报文
    var byXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);            
    memStream.Write(byXml, 0, byXml.Length);
    memStream.Write(contentLine, 0, contentLine.Length);
    webRequest.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

    var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

    memStream.Position = 0;
    var tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    memStream.Close();

    requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    try
    {
        WebResponse wr = webRequest.GetResponse();
        string szContentType = wr.ContentType;
        byte[] szResponse = new byte[wr.ContentLength];
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int iRet = -1;
        int len = 0;
        while ((iRet = wr.GetResponseStream().Read(buf, 0, 1024)) > 0)
        {
            Array.Copy(buf, 0, szResponse, len, iRet);
            len += iRet;
        }

        int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
        byte[] byTmp = new byte[17];
        byte[] byTmp2 = new byte[4];
        string szTmp = string.Empty;
        for (; endIndex + 17 < szResponse.Length;endIndex++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(szResponse, endIndex, byTmp, 0, 17);
            szTmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byTmp);
            if (szTmp.Equals("\r\n--MIME_boundary")) break;
        }
        endIndex += 17;
            //endIndex = szResponse.IndexOf("\r\n--MIME_boundary") + "\r\n--MIME_boundary".Length;
        //szResponse = szResponse.Substring(endIndex);
        string strpath = null;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        strpath = string.Format("face.jpg", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    for (; startIndex + 4 < szResponse.Length; startIndex++)
                    {
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(szResponse, startIndex, byTmp2, 0, 4);
                        szTmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byTmp2);
                        if (szTmp.Equals("\r\n\r\n")) break;
                    }
                    startIndex += 4;
                    for (; endIndex + 17 < szResponse.Length; endIndex++)
                    {
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(szResponse, endIndex, byTmp, 0, 17);
                        szTmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byTmp);
                        if (szTmp.Equals("\r\n--MIME_boundary")) break;
                    }
                    //endIndex = szResponse.IndexOf("\r\n--MIME_boundary");
                    if (startIndex >= szResponse.Length || endIndex >= szResponse.Length) break;
                        //byte[] by = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(szResponse.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
                        fs.Write(szResponse, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
                    endIndex += "\r\n--MIME_boundary".Length;
                    if (startIndex >= szResponse.Length || endIndex >= szResponse.Length) break;
                }
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("capature data wrong", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        //var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        //using (var httpStreamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(),
        //                                                Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
        //{
        //    responseContent = httpStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //}
        //httpWebResponse.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    webRequest.Abort();

    return responseContent;
}
```

**Pasos para realizar este proceso**

Paso1: primero hacemos login con los datos del reloj

paso2: ingresamos un codigo de empleado

paso 3: Click en el boton capturar

**Nota: luego de tomar la fotografia y guardarla en mi carpeta local, la muestra en el picturebox**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En que linea te da el error?

Comment: @Manny 

                // Carga la imagen en el PictureBox
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    pictureBoxFace.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
                }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar o cargar la imagen: " + ex.Message);
            }

Comment: Y el mensaje de error es....?

Comment: @Yussef el parámetro no es valido

Comment: Entiendo que la foto te llega en base64, lo que debería ser un string. Puedes pegarme ese string para probar el asunto?

Comment: En rigor el valor de la variable `szResponse` es lo que te pido

Comment: @Yussef              

szResponse = clHttpClient.HttpCapData(AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strUsername, AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strPassword, szUrl, string.Empty, szRequest);

  // Guarda la imagen en el archivo con el nombre del código de usuario
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(szResponse));

El szResponse esta vacio cuando realizo un debug, podria ser eso?

Comment: No me entiendes. Tu usas esta función "clHttpClient.HttpCapData" que es método de extensión, no sé si tu lo creaste o viene de alguna librería que estas usando, pero no es nativa. Entonces no se lo que te esta devolviendo. En teoría debería devolver la imagen en formato string base64. Ese string es el que te solicito me pases para validar que te está llegando una imagen valida

Comment: Ese metodo ya viene con la libreria y una clase llamada HttpClient del SDK de hikvision. Te agregare la funcion

Comment: @Yussef el string que me pides, en realidad veo que no me devuelve nada  File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(szResponse));

Comment: Si szResponse es un string vacio tu problema es con la API y no tiene nada que ver como cargar la imagen

Answer (score -1):

Agregaga esto dentro del using:

```html
 byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgbyte, 0, imgbyte.Length);
 pictureBoxFace.Image = Image.FromStream(fs,true);
```

Tienes que cargar la imagen en un arreglo de bytes, esto es una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo "system.IO.FileStream en int
 new byte[fs];

Comment: Edite el codigo, prueba nuevamente

Comment: Aun no, me sigue lanzando el mensaje "El parametro no es valido"